# get first and last values in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(10, -1),
                  [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
                   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']],
                  ['X', 'Y'])
```

How do I get the first and last rows, grouped by the first level of the index?

My expected output from the above input:

```
      X   Y
a a   0   1
  d   6   7
b e   8   9
  g  12  13
c h  14  15
  i  16  17
d j  18  19
  j  18  19
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Option 1

```
def first_last(df):
    return df.ix[[0, -1]]

df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(first_last)
```

[image]

---

#### Option 2 - only works if index is unique

```
idx = df.index.to_series().groupby(level=0).agg(['first', 'last']).stack()
df.loc[idx]
```

---

#### Option 3 - per notes below, this only makes sense when there are no NAs

I also abused the `agg` function.  The code below works, but is far uglier.

```
df.reset_index(1).groupby(level=0).agg(['first', 'last']).stack() \
    .set_index('level_1', append=True).reset_index(1, drop=True) \
    .rename_axis([None, None])
```

---

## Note

per @unutbu: `agg(['first', 'last'])` take the firs non-na values.

I interpreted this as, it must then be necessary to run this column by column.  Further, forcing index level=1 to align may not even make sense.

Let's include another test

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(10, -1),
                  [list('aaaabbbccd'),
                   list('abcdefghij')],
                  list('XY'))

df.loc[tuple('aa'), 'X'] = np.nan
```

---

```
def first_last(df):
    return df.ix[[0, -1]]

df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(first_last)
```

[image]

```
df.reset_index(1).groupby(level=0).agg(['first', 'last']).stack() \
    .set_index('level_1', append=True).reset_index(1, drop=True) \
    .rename_axis([None, None])
```

[image]

Sure enough!  This second solution is taking the first valid value in column X.  It is now nonsensical to have forced that value to align with the index a.

Comment: Even though it looks more complicated, the `reset_index/agg` solution is significantly faster than the `groupby/apply` solution when there are a lot of groups. For example, when `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10**3,4)), columns=list('ABCD')).set_index(['A','B']).rename_axis([None, None])`.

Comment: Nice solutions! Might also be good to note that `agg(['first', 'last'])` returns the first and last non-NaN value if available. `apply(first_last)` will return the first and last values even if they are NaN.

Comment: i think for latest pandas version we need df.iloc instead of df.ix see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991397/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-ix

Answer (score 32):

This could be on of the easy solution.

```
df.groupby(level = 0, as_index= False).nth([0,-1])

      X   Y
a a   0   1
  d   6   7
b e   8   9
  g  12  13
c h  14  15
  i  16  17
d j  18  19
```

Hope this helps. (Y)

Answer (score 22):

Please try this:

For last value: `df.groupby('Column_name').nth(-1)`,

For first value: `df.groupby('Column_name').nth(0)`

Comment: But simultaneously?