# drop first and last row from within each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is a follow up question to [get first and last values in a groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38797271/2336654)

How do I drop first and last rows within each group?

I have this `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(10, -1),
                  [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'],
                   ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']],
                  ['X', 'Y'])

df
```

I intentionally made the second row have the same index value as the first row.  I won't have control over the uniqueness of the index.

```
      X   Y
a a   0   1
  a   2   3
  c   4   5
  d   6   7
b e   8   9
  f  10  11
  g  12  13
c h  14  15
  i  16  17
d j  18  19
```

I want this

```
        X   Y
a b   2.0   3
  c   4.0   5
b f  10.0  11
```

Because both groups at level 0 equal to 'c' and 'd' have less than 3 rows, all rows should be dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd apply a similar technique to what I did for the other question:

```
def first_last(df):
    return df.ix[1:-1]

df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(first_last)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note: in pandas version 0.20.0 and above, ix is [deprecated](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated)  and the use of iloc is encouraged instead.

So the `df.ix[1:-1]` should be replaced by `df.iloc[1:-1]`.