# Python- Pandas, filter take last element in group, then first element in group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Follow up question from here: [drop first and last row from within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798058/drop-first-and-last-row-from-within-each-group)

In pandas, how do you drop the last row in the first groupby then the first row for all subsequent entries in the group?

e.g

```
      X   Y
a a   0   1
  a   2   3
  c   4   5
  d   6   7
b e   8   9
  f  10  11
  g  12  13
c h  14  15
  i  16  17
d j  18  19
```

I want this

```
    X   Y
a d 6   7
b e 8   9
c h 14 15
d j 18 19
```

Comment: when you say "I want this" you mean you want to drop those right ?

Comment: Yeah, i want to drop all other rows. Apologies for not being more clear!

Comment: and do you have your first indexes in a list or something ? or are they kind of random ?

Comment: They are random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check first value of first level by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) - first group by [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) and all another by [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
first = df.index.get_level_values(0)[0]
df = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x.tail(1) if x.name == first else x.head(1))
print (df)
      X   Y
a d   6   7
b e   8   9
c h  14  15
d j  18  19
```

Comment: @dmin this is a much much better solution.  +1