# Why doesn't first and last in a groupby give me first and last

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm posting this because the topic just got brought up in another question/answer and the behavior isn't very well documented.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=list('xxxyyy'),
    B=[np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan]
))

   A    B
0  x  NaN
1  x  1.0
2  x  2.0
3  y  3.0
4  y  4.0
5  y  NaN
```

I wanted to get the first and last rows of each group defined by column `'A'`.

I tried

```
df.groupby('A').B.agg(['first', 'last'])

   first  last
A             
x    1.0   2.0
y    3.0   4.0
```

However, This doesn't give me the `np.NaN`s that I expected.

How do I get the actual first and last values in each group?

Comment: Just notice `df.groupby('A').B.agg(['idxmax', 'idxmin'])` keep the same result with `first()` and `last()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use the `.nth` method:

```
>>> gb = df.groupby('A')
>>> gb.nth(0)
     B
A
x  NaN
y  3.0
>>> gb.nth(-1)
     B
A
x  2.0
y  NaN
>>>
```

However, I haven't found a way to aggregate them neatly. Of course, one can always use a `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'first':gb.B.nth(0), 'last':gb.B.nth(-1)})
   first  last
A
x    NaN   2.0
y    3.0   NaN
```

Note: I explicitly used the `gb.B` attribute, or else you have to use `.squeeze`

Comment: didn't know about `nth`

Comment: @piRSquared yep, it's a bit obscure for sure.

Comment: `(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(dict(first=g.nth(0), last=g.nth(-1))))(df.groupby('A').B)`

Comment: Even add a `min` and `max` to it (-:... `(lambda g: g.agg(['min', 'max']).join(pd.DataFrame(dict(first=g.nth(0), last=g.nth(-1)))))(df.groupby('A').B)`

Answer (score 7):

As noted [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797271/get-first-and-last-values-in-a-groupby#comment64965906_38797283) by [**@unutbu**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu):

The [**groupby.first**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [**groupby.last**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) methods return the first and last non-null values respectively.

To get the actual first and last values, do:

```
def h(x):
    return x.values[0]

def t(x):
    return x.values[-1]

df.groupby('A').B.agg([h, t])

     h    t
A          
x  NaN  2.0
y  3.0  NaN
```