# Can and how do I pass arguments to multiple functions used within an aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=list('xxxyyy'),
    B=[np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan]
))

df

   A    B
0  x  NaN
1  x  1.0
2  x  2.0
3  y  3.0
4  y  4.0
5  y  NaN
```

I can use a function within an `agg` and pass an argument like this

```
df.groupby('A').B.agg(pd.Series.head, n=1)

A
x    NaN
y    3.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

However, I want to run the aggregation with `pd.Series.head` and `pd.Series.tail`.  And I want to pass the argument `n=1` to both of them.

I want this aggregation to look like the result below.  It is important to note that I can produce this result already.  My goal here is to figure out how to pass arguments to the multiple functions that are being passed to `agg`.

If it can't be done, an explanation why would be a valid answer.

```
     h    t
A          
x  NaN  2.0
y  3.0  NaN
```

---

**Added Incentive**
If you figure this out... it would be a better solution than the one I have for [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45744800/2336654).  I would encourage whoever answers this one to also answer that one.

Comment: Use lambdas? `lambda x: x.head(1)`?

Comment: Yes, you can see that I do that as my answer for the other question.  But I'm trying to figure out the actual mechanics of passing arguments to multiple functions within an aggregation.

Comment: Not part of the pandas api, but if you're just passing arguments you may find it cleaner to wrap your functions with `functools.partial`, e.g. `partial(pd.Series.head, n=1)`.  Depends on your definition of "clean" though.  You'll retain function names with `partial`, whereas `lambda` kills them, i.e. my previous `partial` example passed in a list will give 'head' as the column name.

Comment: I like it.  Definitely cleaner than a `lambda` when considering the name aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2872) correctly it can't be done:

```
def aggregate(self, func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs):
    _level = kwargs.pop('_level', None)
    if isinstance(func_or_funcs, compat.string_types):
        return getattr(self, func_or_funcs)(*args, **kwargs)  # NOTE: (*args, **kwargs) are passed to the function

    if hasattr(func_or_funcs, '__iter__'):
        ret = self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(func_or_funcs,    # NOTE: `*args, **kwargs` got lost ...
                                             (_level or 0) + 1)  
    ...
```

**NOTE:** if `func_or_funcs` has `'__iter__'` attribute `*args` and `**kwargs` will get ignored...

Comment: This is the way, or lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

You may pass lambdas within a dictionary to the agg

```
>> df.groupby('A').B.agg({'h': lambda s: s.head(1), 't': lambda s: s.tail(1)})
```

But you may not pass it in the future

> FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version

I prefer to rename lambdas and prevent

> SpecificationError: Function names must be unique, found multiple
>   named

```
>> h = lambda s: s.head(1)
>> h.__name__ = 'h'
>> t = lambda s: s.tail(1)
>> t.__name__ = 't'
>> df.groupby('A').B.agg([h, t])
>>
>>     h     t
>> A        
>> x   NaN   2.0
>> y   3.0   NaN
```

It may seem that 5 lines is too much, but the lines are quite short!

One possible workaround in passing additional kwargs to the agg functions is to use `partial`

```
>> from functools import partial
>> df.groupby('A').B.agg([partial(pd.Series.head, n=1),
>>                        partial(pd.Series.tail, n=1)])
>>
>>     head  tail
>> A        
>> x   NaN   2.0
>> y   3.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  However, as I've said [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745029/can-and-how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-multiple-functions-used-within-an-aggregation/45745429#comment78448010_45745029).  I'm trying to use the pandas api to pass arguments to the functions.  I'm able to do it with one function.  How do I do it with multiple functions?