# Python pandas get first and last index, duplicate if first is also the last, of group in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on getting the index of the first and last occurrence of IDs in a data frame. But if the ID only appears once, then the last occurrence will be the same as the first one.

For example, a data like this:

```
ID  Date
A   1/1/2015
A   1/5/2016
A   1/3/2017
B   1/3/2017
C   1/5/2016
C   1/7/2016
```

and the output will be

```
ID  Index   Date
A   0   1/1/2015
A   2   1/3/2017
B   3   1/3/2017
B   3   1/3/2017
C   4   1/5/2016
C   5   1/5/2016
```

Note: I don't really need the index, it is just for making the question clearer.

I have tried using `data.groupby('ID', as_index=False).nth([0,-1])` but in the example above, this will only output B once.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([d.iloc[[0, -1]] for _, d in df.groupby('ID')])

  ID      Date
0  A  1/1/2015
2  A  1/3/2017
3  B  1/3/2017
3  B  1/3/2017
4  C  1/5/2016
5  C  1/7/2016
```

---

### Using `agg`

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(['first', 'last']).stack().reset_index('ID')

      ID      Date
first  A  1/1/2015
last   A  1/3/2017
first  B  1/3/2017
last   B  1/3/2017
first  C  1/5/2016
last   C  1/7/2016
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code and it works. However, I have found one funny behavior with `agg`, if for example (using the same example above) the Date in the last occurence of C is NaN, `agg` will simply print the first Date of C (1/5/2016), is there a way to keep the NaN?

Comment: Ahh!  That is the intended behavior of `'first'` and `'last'` in an `agg` context.  This is very similar to a question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/q/45744800/2336654

Comment: See updated answer.  I like the new answer better for your objective.

Comment: I like `agg` better as it gives much more faster results. But shame `first` and `last` givesnon-NaN values, it was the fastest implementation so far. Thanks again @piRSquared